# React Router is able to do the routing only if started from root url

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a React app that also uses Redux and ReactRouter.

My problem is the following:

When I launch the app and go to the root url, I can normally navigate inside the app, and the routes in the navigation bar will be changing as I navigate.

However, if I type in the navigation bar any url other than the root, I get a weird error:
[image]
[image]

I don't really get how one can get such an error.

If I go to `localhost:1337/` and then click on the item with the link `/cars/1`, everything will be fine and the component will successfully get rendered. If I type `localhost:1337/cars/1` right away (or any other *existing* route) I get this error.

Here's how I initialize the react-router and define my routes:

index.js:

```
require('./style/style.css');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reduxPromise from 'redux-promise';

import routes from './routes';
import reducers from './reducers';


const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
    reduxPromise
)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.container.app')
);
```

routes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute, Redirect } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';
import CarsIndex from './containers/cars-index';
import CarNew from './containers/car-new';
import CarShow from './containers/car-show';
import CarEdit from './containers/car-edit';
import SignIn from './containers/signin';
import auth from './auth/auth';


function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
    if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
        replace({
            pathname: '/authenticate',
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        });
    }
}

function filterLoggedIn(nextState, replace) {
    if (auth.loggedIn()) {
        replace({
            pathname: '/',
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        });
    }
}

export default (
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={CarsIndex} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route path='cars/new' component={CarNew} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route path='cars/:id' component={CarShow} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route path='cars/edit/:id' component={CarEdit} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route path='authenticate' component={SignIn} onEnter={filterLoggedIn} />
        <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
    </Route>
);
```

My server is a small express.js app and it redirects any requests other than `/api/*` to the `index.html` page.

Here's a part from my `server.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
const app = express();
const pathToStatic = path.join(__dirname, 'static');
express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static'));
app.use(express.static(pathToStatic));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/api/cars', (req, res) => {
    return Car.find((err, cars) => {
        if (!err) {
            return res.send(cars);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            res.statusCode = 500;
            return res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
        }
    });
});
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(pathToStatic, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Express server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

---

Have you encountered such an issue? Could you help me to find out the soultion to this problem?

Comment: Your server (because it is handling the path first) must be configured to return `index.html` if no routes are matched.  This then hands control of route resolution back to the client.

Comment: @DavinTryon My server does exactly that (or at least I think so). I've added my server code to the bottom of the question

Comment: In component `CarShow` do you make an api request?  Is this request returning `index.html` as well, when it should be returning json?  Check out the network tab in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: @DavinTryon Almost every component inside the `App` route does the api requests that return json.

Comment: It looks to me like one of your api requests is returning some html.  This is why you get the json parse error that it encountered a `<` in the response.

Comment: @DavinTryon I've double-checked, and it seems like every `/api*` request returns a json object, no html

Comment: Why is `bundle.js` showing up as html in your sources?  make sure to send javascript for your `bundle.js`.  The issue seems to be that you are sending `index.html` for all of your page resources as well.

Comment: @DavinTryon Honestly, I've no idea. Here's the result of my `localhost:1337/` request: http://i.imgur.com/uQccYHM.png , and here's the result of `localhost:1337/cars/1` http://i.imgur.com/F7K9guD.png . Bundle.js really for some reason gets returned as html...

Comment: @DavinTryon Ohh, now I get it. Might that be the issue that my express app serves bundle.js and index.html as static assets and at the same time serves the index.html page for `::1337/*` requests as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116787/discussion-between-davin-tryon-and-denis-yakovenko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot shows that `bundle.js` (when requested) is returning `index.html`.

This is because your express routes handle route `api/cars` and then default **everything** else to index.html.

Of course all your resources that appear on `index.html` must also be sent the browser.  This includes `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` which the browser will request once it gets `index.html` the first time.

So, you must have some way to allow express to handle requests for the resources that `index.html` needs.

A popular solution to this is to *mount* an assets directory and place that above the default route.  Something like:

```
// api routes

app.use(express.static('assets'));

// default route
```

Then make sure your `bundle.js` is inside the assets directory.  And then that the script tag looks like `<script src="/assets/bundle.js"></script>`.